# Will strtok(null) cause any bugs?

Tags: php

PHP script to read in user action requests and parse them to their components. Example, user types in `SET Colour = Blue` or `describe Chocolate Cake = The best cake ever!` I'm using like this:

```
$actionKeyword = strtok( $actionRequest, " " ); // keyword followed by space
$name = strtok( "=" ); // Then name followed by equals
$description = strtok(null); // get the rest of the string
```

I could not find anything on getting the rest of the string. PHP.net's example was using spaces to tokenize each word but there was no character I could think of that might not be part of the description. This solution works in my tests.

Is there a side effect or special case this would fail on? Or is this a perfectly safe and acceptable way of getting the rest of the line?

Comment: There shouldn't be any nasty side effects. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any bugs now, as `null` gets converted to an empty string when `strtok` parses its parameters.

But you probably will be a bit safer if you use `strtok('')` form explicitly. The reason why it works is that `strtok` expects a stringified list of delimiter characters as a token param. So an empty string here is basically an empty list of delimiters. And no delimiters to look for means the whole remaining string to return. )

By the way, this advice is given [in comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php#7817) at the manual page. )

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that - or just call `strtok("")` without any token ...

```
$actionKeyword = strtok( "describe Chocolate Cake = The best cake ever!", " " ); // keyword followed by space
$name = strtok( "=" ); // Then name followed by equals
$description = strtok(""); // get the rest of the string
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/NRh6ndaD)

Note: you will need to trim it as it contains the leading space